# Triggering Worksheet Change in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is more of a general question but I was wondering what exactly triggers a Workbook_SheetChange() on Excel VBA. It claims to change when a value in a cell is changed, but when you try and drag instead of entering a value into a new cell, the macro doesn't trigger. Is there any way to go around that or is there another way to trigger a macro that will detect any change in a workbook?

Comment: `Workbook_SheetChange()` Should only trigger when you change sheets, are you talking about `Workbook_SelectionChange()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "try and drag"?  Are you referring to auto-fill?  I'm having a hard time replicating this.

Comment: @Mr.Burns - you're thinking of `SheetActivate`. See [Workbook.SheetChange Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx).

Comment: Any editing change on any worksheet triggers `Workbook_SheetChange` including dragging or adding/removing formulas. It **doesn't** trigger when a formula changes its value from a recalculation. You are likely confusing the **sh** parameter and possibly not dealing with situation(s) where Target is more than one cell.

Answer (score 0):

For me it **does** seem to trigger the change event when dragging and dropping cells.

I'm using (In the "ThisWorkbook" Module);

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

Are you definitely using the WORK**BOOK** event and not the WORK**SHEET** event?

Edit: Phrasing